# how do i share mysite's videos & comments on facebook?

Tags: web-services, facebook, jsf-2

Hi I have been looking at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/facebook.html but I'm not shure this is the way.

Thank you very much best regards
Ignacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly found several answears at www.facebook.com/developers